# Note 4 camera not focusing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

New galaxy note 4 camera doesn't focus at first,  it will only work when I shake my camera or thump it real hard.  Had anyone had this issue or have an idea on his to fix it?

Comment: I am having this problem since the Lollipop update. I was hoping to find a solution. I also find that shaking the phone forces it to focus. I'm afraid it may be a HW issue that started happening about the time I upgraded the OS and I'm merely connecting the two events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue on Note 4s running Android L. The most common suggestion seems to be a replacement, as the issue is not software based but actually a loose sensor within the phone itself. I suggest contacting your phone service provider.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with most of Galaxy s5, s6, Note 4, etc... I took to my local Samsung Store here in Los Angeles and they replaced the camera right the way under the warranty. It takes about 30 minutes.